# Three UIViewControllers on the same window

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I want to develop the following application: on top I have a navigation bar, in the middle a TableViewController and on the bottom I have a custom control that is actually a slider (when I move the slider I want to present another TableViewController - but my navigation bar remains the same). And when I select a cell in the TableView I want to push a new ViewController (so I will change my navigation bar) and I will also dismiss my custom control. I have attached a picture of the prototype of my application.How would you suggest that I should implement this? My custom control is designed using IB so I think I should use the old way, using .xib files, not the Storyboard.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really mean separate view controllers? Everything you've described could be handled with views, in a way that's compatible with all recent versions of iOS

If you really want the 3 parts of your screen to use separate view controllers, you can really only do that under iOS 5 (or later). Starting with iOS 5, view controllers can contain other "child" view controllers. You can create your own container view controller.

Look at the method addChildViewController: to set up view controllers as children of hte current view controller. You add all your children first, and then add their content views as subviews of the parent view controller.

It sounds to me like you would want a navigation controller who's root view controller is a container view controller with multiple child view controllers. If you want to swap out one of the children, use transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion: to switch child view controllers.

Comment: I am not sure I want separate view controllers. I know I want to use my CustomControl (the slider) to swap out the middle TableView, and when I press on a cell from the TableView I want to push a new ViewController (so I want to change my navigation bar, by adding the "Back Button"). So you're saying that I can use addChildViewController to add two view controllers for my two subviews (the TableView and my CustomControl) ?

Comment: Actually, I think I want a navigation controller and a table view controller. Because I can set my navigation controller to be the deleagte of my CustomControl (which is basically a subclass of UIControl). So when I press on a cell from the TableView I will perform a push, but how can I swap the TableViewCotnroller from the middle and still keeping my CustomControl at the bottom of my window?

Comment: @Cosmin You do not need to swap your Table View Controller at all. Just use the existing table view controller and tell the table view to reload its data with [[self tableView] reloadData]. Then, have your UITableViewDataSource supply the data from the new day instead of the old day.

Comment: Yes, but I want to make a transition effect when I do that. Is that possible if I only reload the data?